# ID of Repeater is not coming in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to pull some data from the database into repeater, but I am not able to get the `ID` of the repeater in code-behind. Please help what might be the possible reason ??

See my code though

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptNews" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="Newsdiv">
                        <p class="Newspara"><a href="#"><%#Eval("title")%></a></p>
                        <p class="NewsDate1"><a href="#">Click here</a> to know more</p>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

In Codebehind:-

I want to call ID `rptNews` in the codebehind, but it is not coming

Comment: What is the problem ? Is repeater nested in anyother server data control ?

Comment: @CoderofCode: No it is not nested anywhere, still Not getting it

Comment: Check in your designer page code if the control is exists.

Comment: try closing down the visual studio and open it again as it will syn the designer file

Comment: @HaseebAsif: I tried that but still not getting the `ID`

Comment: @CoderofCode: I dont have designer page of that..

Comment: Kindly provide the page declaration (first line of aspx file)

Comment: @HaseebAsif: `<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/CSRFrontEnd/index1MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="News.aspx.cs" Inherits="News" %>
` let me know if you need anything else

Comment: @NadeemKhan go to code behind there should be News partial class right click on news and find all references.you should get another partial class in your result apart from that code bind class. That another class should have your control declared. If not you need to add control there manually

Comment: In the page Declaration, update the Inherits="XXX.News" where XXX is namespace of News class

Comment: @JenishRabadiya: Can you explain more in detail, I m not getting what you are trying to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason is control not defined in your designer.cs page. Check your designer.cs page see if this exists:

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater rptNews;
```

If not then add it manually

Comment: There is not a designer.cs page for that aspx page. Here Only I have aspx and cs page.

Comment: which one vs you are using?

Comment: other controls on the page accessible?

Comment: I am getting the namespace name in the Intellis when I am calling the ID of the repeater

Comment: what if you right click the page and choose "Convert to Web Application" from the context menu

Comment: from where to click and convert ??. Sorry went for lunch

Comment: Yes not Id is coming, but when I see the aspx page on the browser it gives me error at `<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/CSRFrontEnd/index1MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="News" Codebehind="News.aspx.cs" %>`

Comment: Thanks Irfan, your answer gave me hint to the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you renamed the file or the class and the codebehind is no more "attached"  to the aspx page.

Check in the aspx the directives at the beginning if the inherits value correspond to the name of class in the codebehind